# How to create XML element reference?

Tags: xml

In the XML, there is a huge list of elements that is used at many places. The example list is as follows

```
            <platform>PLAT_X86_SLES_11_SP3</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_64_SLES_11_SP3</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_SLES_12</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_SLES_12_SP1</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12_SP1</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_SLES_12_SP2</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12_SP2</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_RHEL_6_5</platform>
            <platform>PLAT_X86_64_RHEL_6_5</platform>
```

The list is being used in full excluding only 2 or 3 platforms at many places like below.

```
<platform_support>
    <platform>PLAT_X86_SLES_11_SP3</platform>
    <platform>PLAT_X86_64_SLES_11_SP3</platform>
    <platform>PLAT_X86_SLES_12</platform>
    <platform>PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12</platform>
    <platform>PLAT_X86_SLES_12_SP1</platform>
    <platform>PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12_SP1</platform>
</platform_support>
```

what I want to do is, I want to define a full list in the beginning and use the reference of it in my  tag. Just like below:

```
<platforms>
            <platform index="1">PLAT_X86_SLES_11_SP3</platform>
            <platform index="2">PLAT_X86_64_SLES_11_SP3</platform>
            <platform index="3">PLAT_X86_SLES_12</platform>
            <platform index="4">PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12</platform>
            <platform index="5">PLAT_X86_SLES_12_SP1</platform>
            <platform index="6">PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12_SP1</platform>
            <platform index="7">PLAT_X86_SLES_12_SP2</platform>
            <platform index="8">PLAT_X86_64_SLES_12_SP2</platform>
            <platform index="9">PLAT_X86_RHEL_6_5</platform>
            <platform index="10">PLAT_X86_64_RHEL_6_5</platform>
</platforms>
```

usage as below:

```
<platform_support index_list="1,2,3,4,5,6">
</platform_support>
```

another usage as below:

```
<platform_support index_list="3,4,5,6,7,8">
</platform_support>
```

I don't know if there are any such features in XML available or not. If you have any idea how do I achieve this please mention.

Is this a good idea to do this? Because every time a small change in requirement requires a change to many places. This is just one example I have written. I have a huge XML of 4500 lines of code having many such lists.

Comment: What you suggest does not violate any XML rules. It's OK to have an attribute whose value is interpreted as a list of references to other elements. If it solves your problem, then it might be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for comment. My question was how to achieve this. Is that possible to achieve it through some XML feature or do I need to write the logic in XML interpreter only?

Comment: XML is just a way to structure data. If you want to change how your XML files are structured, you will have to do it by hand or write a program to do it. XML in itself does not have any "features" that can do this. I don't know what you mean by "XML interpreter".

Answer (score 0):

look i am not pretty good at it but here is what i can offer in that.
there is a pretty topic in XML called XQuery that will help you very much.
think about XQuery as a SQL for the database you can query the xmal data you have using it.

the XQuery has a sequence which could be $items=1,2,3,5,89 or $items = orange, apple, somenames, anything

so here is a tip.
u can use the index attribute as you illustrate above in your question along side with FLOWR (a Xquery technique ) and use your custom list of indecies as a sequence.
and here is a tip about what i am talking about

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xquery/xquery_sequences.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xquery/xquery_flwor.htm

Note the FLOWR can be nested which is pretty awesome.

Comment: Is this possible to do in the same XML file or do I need to write another file of code to achieve this?

Comment: i did not think altering original file is a good idea . filtering and selection has to be done in separate file. even a temporary file will be a better idea.